# Cannot get values from FormData - angularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

This may be somewhere similar to a lot of questions but I can't find a working solution in them. Which made me ask this question.

So I've a razor file and angular file as :-

```js
angular.module('App').controller("ModalController", function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $compile) {
    $scope.sdata1 = {};

    $scope.SaveQuotation = function () {
        var frm = $("#formSaveQuotationDetail");
        var formData = new FormData(frm[0]);
        alert(formData.get('VendorName'));

        $http({ url: window.SaveQuotation,
                method: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
        }).success(
            function (res) {
                if (res == 'Saved Successfully!') {
                    $scope.FetchQuotationList();
                }
                else {
                    alert(res)
                }
            }
        ).error(function (res) { showHttpErr(res); });

    }
    }
```

```html
@model NtierMvc.Model.QuotationEntity

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "QuotationDetails";
}

<div ng-app="App">
<div ng-controller="ModalController" class="row">
    <form id="formSaveQuotationDetail">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" hidden>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            User Initial
                        </label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserInitial, new
                   {
                       @class = "form-control requiredValidation",
                       @id = "UserInitial",
                       @readonly = "readonly"
                   })
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UnitNo)
                        @*<span class="HideValidMsg">Please Enter Valid Letter Number</span>
                <span class="HideValidMsg">Please Select Post</span>*@
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            VendorId
                        </label>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.VendorId, new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListVendorId, "DataStringValueField", "DataTextField", Model.VendorId),
                           new
                           {
                               @class = "form-control requiredValidation",
                               @id = "VendorId",
                               @data_inneraction = "validationCall",
                               @onfocusout = "return ValidateRequiredFieldsOnFocusOut(this)",
                               ng_model= "VendorId",
                               ng_change = "GetVendorDetails(VendorId)"

                           })
                        <span class="HideValidMsg">Please Select VendorId</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            Vendor Name
                        </label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.VendorName, new
                   {
                       @class = "form-control requiredValidation",
                       @id = "VendorName",
                       @onfocusout = "return ValidateRequiredFieldsOnFocusOut(this)",
                       @readonly = "readonly",
                       ng_model = "VendorName",
                   })
                        <span class="HideValidMsg">Please Select VendorId</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            Country
                        </label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Country, new
               {
                   @class = "form-control requiredValidation",
                   @id= "Country",
                   @placeholder = "Select Vendor ID",
                   ng_model = "Country",
                   @readonly = "readonly",
                   @style = "width = '50%'"
               })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CountryId, new { ng_model = "CountryId", @hidden = "hidden" })
                        <span class="HideValidMsg">Please Select VendorId</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            Geo Area <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GeoArea, new
                   {
                       @class = "form-control requiredValidation",
                       @id = "GeoArea",
                       @placeholder = "Select Vendor ID",
                       ng_model = "GeoArea",
                       @ng_hide = "GeoArea == null"
                   })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GeoCode, new { ng_model = "GeoCode", @hidden = "hidden" })
                        <span class="HideValidMsg">Please Select Vendor ID</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            Quote Type <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.QuoteType, new
                   {
                       @class = "form-control requiredValidation",
                       @id = "QuoteType",
                       @placeholder = "Quote Type",
                       ng_model = "QuoteType"
                   })
                        <span class="HideValidMsg">Please Enter QuoteType</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            File Number <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FileNo, new
                   {
                       @class = "form-control requiredValidation",
                       @id = "FileNo",
                       @placeholder = "File Number",
                       ng_model = "FileNo"
                   })
                        <span class="HideValidMsg">Please Enter Quotation Reference</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            Enquiry Reference
                        </label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EnqRef, new
                   {
                       @class = "form-control requiredValidation",
                       @id = "EnqRef",
                       @placeholder = "Enquiry Reference",
                       @onfocusout = "return ValidateRequiredFieldsOnFocusOut(this)",
                       ng_model = "EnqRef"
                   })
                        <span class="HideValidMsg">Please Select Enquiry Reference</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @*<div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Quotation Type</label>
                <div class="m-radio-inline">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.QuoteType, new
              {
                  @class = "form-control requiredValidation",
                  @id = "QuoteType",
                  @placeholder = "Quotation Type",
                  @onfocusout = "return ValidateRequiredFieldsOnFocusOut(this)"
              })
                </div>
                <span class="HideValidMsg">Please Select Quotation Type</span>
            </div>
        </div>*@


                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            Enquiry Date
                        </label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EnqDt, new
                   {
                       @class = "form-control requiredValidation ApprovalDate",
                       @id = "EnqDt",
                       @placeholder = "dd/MM/yyyy",
                       @style = "disabled :disabled",
                       @onfocusout = "return ValidateRequiredFieldsOnFocusOut(this)",
                       ng_model = "EnqDt"
                   })
                        <span class="HideValidMsg">Please Select Enquiry Date</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            Enquiry For
                        </label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EnqFor, new
                   {
                       @class = "form-control requiredValidation",
                       @id = "EnqFor",
                       @placeholder = "Enquiry For",
                       @onfocusout = "return ValidateRequiredFieldsOnFocusOut(this)",
                       ng_model = "EnqFor"
                   })
                        <span class="HideValidMsg">Please Enter Enquiry For</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            Product Group
                        </label>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProdGrp, new SelectList(@ViewBag.ListProdGrpId, "DataStringValueField", "DataTextField", Model.VendorId),
                           new
                           {
                               @class = "form-control requiredValidation",
                               @id = "ProdGrp",
                               @onfocusout = "return ValidateRequiredFieldsOnFocusOut(this)",
                               ng_model= "ProdGrp"
                           })
                        <span class="HideValidMsg">Please Select Product Group</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            Quote Number
                        </label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.QuoteNo, new
                   {
                       @class = "form-control requiredValidation",
                       @id = "QuoteNo",
                       @placeholder = "Quote No",
                       @onfocusout = "return ValidateRequiredFieldsOnFocusOut(this)",
                       @readonly = "readonly"
                   })
                        <span class="HideValidMsg">Please Select Quote No</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            Quote Date <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.QuoteDate, new
                   {
                       @class = "form-control requiredValidation ApprovalQuoteDate",
                       @id = "QuoteDate",
                       @placeholder = "dd/MM/yyyy",
                       @style = "disabled :disabled",
                       @onfocusout = "return ValidateRequiredFieldsOnFocusOut(this)",
                       ng_model = "QuoteDate"
                   })
                        <span class="HideValidMsg">
                            Please Select Quote Date
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            Quote Validity
                        </label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.QuoteValidity, new
                   {
                       @class = "form-control requiredValidation ApprovalDate",
                       @id = "QuoteValidity",
                       @placeholder = "dd/MM/yyyy",
                       @style = "disabled :disabled",
                       @onfocusout = "return ValidateRequiredFieldsOnFocusOut(this)",
                       ng_model = "QuoteValidity"
                   })
                        <span class="HideValidMsg">Please Select Quotation Validity</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4" hidden>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            BG Request
                        </label>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BgReq, new
                           {
                               @class = "form-control requiredValidation",
                               @id = "BgReq",
                               @placeholder = "BG Req",
                               @onfocusout = "return ValidateRequiredFieldsOnFocusOut(this)",
                               ng_model = "BgReq"
                           })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="HideValidMsg">Please Select Letter Date</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            Inspection <span class="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Inspection, new
                   {
                       @class = "form-control requiredValidation",
                       @id = "Inspection",
                       @placeholder = "Inspection",
                       @onfocusout = "return ValidateRequiredFieldsOnFocusOut(this)",
                       ng_model = "Inspection"
                   })
                        <span class="HideValidMsg">Please Select Inspection</span>
                        @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Vicinity.NameofInstitute, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            Status
                        </label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Status, new
                   {
                       @class = "form-control requiredValidation",
                       @id = "Status",
                       @placeholder = "Status",
                       @onfocusout = "return ValidateRequiredFieldsOnFocusOut(this)",
                       ng_model = "Status"
                   })
                        <span class="HideValidMsg">Please Select Status</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label">
                            Remarks
                        </label>
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Remarks, new
                   {
                       @class = "form-control requiredValidation",
                       @id = "Remarks",
                       @placeholder = "Remarks",
                       @onfocusout = "return ValidateRequiredFieldsOnFocusOut(this)",
                       ng_model = "Remarks"
                   })
                        <span class="HideValidMsg">Please Select Remarks</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 pt-4 text-center">
                    <button style="font-size:18px" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal" id="save_results" ng-click="SaveQuotation()">Save</button>
                    <button style="font-size:18px" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.VendorDetail = '@Url.Action("GetQuoteVendorDetail", "Technical")';
        window.SaveQuotation = '@Url.Action("SaveQuotationDetails", "Technical")';
        //$('#save_results').on("click", function () {
        //    QuotationDetails.FinalSave();
        //})

    });
    //LEASE DATE AND EXP LEASE DATE VALIDATION
    $('.ApprovalDate').datepicker({

        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        autoclose: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        endDate: '',
    });
    $('.ApprovalQuoteDate').datepicker({

        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        autoclose: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        endDate: 'today',
    });
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/CustomJS/common.js"></script>
```

My problem is when I hit the Save button. I get all null values in my c# controller as under:-

```
public ActionResult SaveQuotationDetails(QuotationEntity cusE)
    {
        model = new BaseModel();
        ViewBag.ListVENDORTYPE = model.GetMasterTableList("Master.Vendor", "Id", "VendorType");
        ViewBag.ListVENDOR_NATURE = model.GetMasterTableList("Master.Vendor", "Id", "VendorNature");
        ViewBag.ListFUNCTION_AREA = model.GetMasterTableList("Master.FunctionalArea", "Id", "FunctionArea");

        cusE.UserInitial = Session["UserName"].ToString();
        cusE.ipAddress = ERPContext.UserContext.IpAddress;
        cusE.UnitNo = Session["UserId"].ToString();

        string result = objManager.SaveTechnicalDetails(cusE);

        TempData["VendorName"] = cusE.VendorName;
        TempData["UserName"] = cusE.UserInitial;
        string data = string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && (result == GeneralConstants.Inserted || result == GeneralConstants.Updated))
        {
            //Payment Gateway
            data = GeneralConstants.SavedSuccess;
        }
        else
        {
            data = GeneralConstants.NotSavedError;
        }

        return new JsonResult { Data = data, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

I've already defined everything , but can't understand the problem. Pls Help.

Comment: Note you need `transformRequest: angular.identity,` when sending FormData object. Default is to transform to json which isn't possible with FormData

Comment: @georgeawg yes it is adding both id and name attribute.

Comment: The `.success` method has been [removed from the AngularJS framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angularjs-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Comment: but I've another method with .success working perfectly.

Comment: That means the code is using an obsolete version of AngularJS.

Comment: @charlietfl I used transformRequest: angular.identity , still same problem. I get null values.

Comment: Check the Network Tab in the Developer Console. Is the data null when in the XHR?

Comment: Am not very familiar with .Net but suspect issue is in that code. Should work exactly the same as a regular form submit without ajax